# Help booting from disk

Tags: 12.04, boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

I already have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS installed on my computer, but I would like to get Windows back onto it. The only problem is that I can't boot from any CD/USB/SD, all I get is the GRUB boot menu, without an option for the Windows 7 install CD. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had this in the past, I had to manually boot from the Disk/USB by going into the 'Boot Menu' when your PC boots you will see at the bottom of the screen something like 'F12 Boot Menu' it is usually F12, F4, F7 and I think I once saw Backspace. From here manually select the Windows 7 media and press Enter, from here you should be fine. If you have a really old PC it might not have a 'Boot Menu' so you will have to go into the BIOS (when the PC is booting hit the corresponding 'F' kry to get into the BIOS [Usually F2] and change the boot order so the Windows Media is the first priority, your PC will most likely have a boot menu.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but whenever I boot my computer, whatever 'F' key I press, nothing happens. Ubuntu just keeps loading.

Comment: Did your PC come with Windows 8? And when your PC boots do you see any 'F' keys at the bottom?

Comment: I thought it would have been much more complicated. Even though I'm not running on a PC, (I'm using a MacBook Pro), it seemed like it would be a problem with Ubuntu, but I just had to hold down 'C'.

Comment: Ah, glad you solved it. After you install Windows 7 use the OS X CD that came with your mac so you can install all the drivers for the hardware, and get everything working. Here is a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVfRQ0YIDUI skip to around 6:00